# Why doesn't the $1 syntax work for all queries?

Tags: postgresql, parameter, copy

I tried to do this:

```
COPY postgres_log FROM $1 WITH csv;
```

And with a separately sent file path, like I make all normal queries (SELECT/UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE). However, it gives:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
```

Um... So does that mean that I'm forced to send it a scary string like this?

```
COPY postgres_log FROM '/full/path/to/logfileblablabla.csv' WITH csv;
```

If so, why? Why don't all query types support the parameterized queries interface? Isn't this like *asking* to enable SQL query injection vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you cannot use parameters with `COPY`.

Why? Because nobody has implemented it. Feel free to come up with a patch.

Currently only `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` support parameters.

You can use the `format` function with the `%L` format to comfortably construct an SQL string with a string literal while avoiding the danger of SQL injection.